# How configure PySpark in PyCharm? I have a problem

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have problem to configure PySpark in PyCharm.
I use: Java JDK 1.0_311, Python 3.10.1, spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2. I followed this tutorial: https://kaizen.itversity.com/setup-spark-development-environment-pycharm-and-python/

My code is:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark=SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("SparkExamples.com").getOrCreate()

rdd=spark.sparkContext.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5,6])

print(rdd.count())
```

This is the error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
22/01/07 22:04:33 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Python not finded; Esegui senza argomenti per installare da Microsoft Store o disabilitare il collegamento da impostazioni > Gestisci app Alias di esecuzione.
22/01/07 22:04:46 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
22/01/07 22:04:49 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:535)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:189)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:175)
    ... 14 more
22/01/07 22:04:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (Domenico-PC executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:535)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:189)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:175)
    ... 14 more
```

22/01/07 22:04:49 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 3 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\domen\PycharmProjects\pythonProject16\main.py", line 7, in 
print(rdd.count())
File "C:\Users\domen\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1237, in count
File "C:\Users\domen\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1226, in sum
File "C:\Users\domen\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1080, in fold
File "C:\Users\domen\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 950, in collect
File "C:\Users\domen\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1309, in **call**
File "C:\Users\domen\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 111, in deco
File "C:\Users\domen\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (Domenico-PC executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:535)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:189)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:175)
... 14 more

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2352)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2351)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2351)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
at

```
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2591)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2533)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2522)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2214)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2235)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2254)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2279)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1030)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:535)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:189)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:175)
    ... 14 more

[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 7) / 8]
Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I use: Java JDK 1.8_311

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a network restriction in your environment created by anti-virus, firewall, vpn client, etc...

Try setting environment variable `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` to `127.0.0.1` in your PyCharm configuration and see if it helps.

Comment: I solve the problem adding the environment variable `PYSPARK_PYTHON` to `python`. Thanks the same for the help.

Comment: Consider adding your solution to your question and accept it, it will help future users

Comment: How can I do it? I'm new, sorry

Comment: Simply add new answer to this question and accept it

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Connection between pyspark and python not being established correctly

Solution:
set `PYSPARK_PYTHON` environment variable to `python`.

[image]

Note: make sure to restart your cmd or shell after adding environment variables